# wxPython inherit font

Tags: python, fonts, wxpython

How to avoid writing for each label:

```
static_text.SetFont(wx.Font(...))
static_text.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(...))
```

and instead inherit the font from parent element or something?

Answer (score 2):

If you change the font of the parent container you get that font for all the widgets on it. For example changing the font for the Frame instance, font gets changed in the static text and the checkbox without the need to set them separately:

[image]

Afaik if you want to modify existing code you can not access to write the SetFont line, then you need these classes to have been written with that in mind. The obvious thing would be to have the Font set in a method outside `__init__` in the parent class in order to overwrite it in your class that will be inheriting from the restricted-access class

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
class Label(wx.StaticText):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.StaticText.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.SetFont(wx.Font(...))
        self.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colout(...))
...
static_text = Label(...)
```

Comment: This is an obvious solution, but what if you need to deal with existing code?

Comment: @Halst You can set desired font for parent and it will be applied to all child controls, so just don't call `SetFont` for the labels. If this doesn't work for you then try to call `InheritAttributes` method for each control.

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing towards InheritAttributes. It works, however it still needs to be called on every static-label in my case. Any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: @Halst It is difficult to say why it is not working without `InheritAttributes` without seeing you code, but one of my guesses is that you set font for parent when children are already created, to get the attributes inheritance work font attributes must be set before children created.